# How can I tell if Snapshot Isolation is turned on?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2005/2008, how can I tell if Snapshot Isolation is turned on? I know *how* to turn it on, but I can't find the incantation to get google to tell me how to query the state of the Snapshot Isolation option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

right click on the databases directory in the object explorer and start powershell. 
type:
`get-childitem|select name, snapshotisolationstate`
and press return

Comment: wow, is the PS really necessary?

Answer (score 77):

Powershell, really?  what's wrong with good ol' fashioned T-SQL?

[sys.databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) is what you want.  It has human readable description columns like snapshot_isolation_state_desc

```
SELECT snapshot_isolation_state_desc from sys.databases 
where name='adventureworks'
```

Comment: No, not wholly necessary but I'm just starting to learn PS so took a look to see how it could be done and thought I'd share .. !

Comment: as much as i hate to admit it, it is cool

Comment: to be honest, I'm struggling to see its going to be a lot of use to me, we only have 30ish servers. If I wanted the snapshot isolation from every database on every server then I guess PS might be better than T-SQL.. for now I'm seeing it just as an alternative, I'll use it here and there I expect.

Comment: I can't edit because it's less than a six-character change, but for other confused souls who copy and paste the query, note that it should be sys.database*s* and not sys.database.

Answer (score 17):

Expanding on nicks response from above..

The following will return information about all of your databases

```
    select name
        , s.snapshot_isolation_state
        , snapshot_isolation_state_desc
        , is_read_committed_snapshot_on
        , recovery_model
        , recovery_model_desc
        , collation_name
    from sys.databases s
```

Answer (score 4):

Or using T-SQL code:

```
SELECT
'Current Isolation State:' [ ],
CASE is_read_committed_snapshot_on
        WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF'
    END AS [Read Committed Snapsot State]
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'MyDatabaseName'
```

Comment: This answer is for read_committed_snapshot, not for Snapshot Isolation Level like the OP requested.  They are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

> **How to test whether the snapshot transaction isolation level is enabled**
>
> To test whether the snapshot transaction isolation level is enabled,
>   follow these steps:
>
> 1. Start SQL Server Profiler.
> 2. Create a new trace to connect to the data source that you specified in the Analysis Services project.
> 3. In the **Trace Properties** dialog box, click the **Events Selection** tab.
> 4. In the TransactionID column, click to select the check boxes in the row for the SQL:BatchCompleted event and in the row for the
>      SQL:BatchStarting event.
>
> *Note To display the TransactionID column, click to select the **Show all columns** check box.*
>
> 5. Click **Run** to start the trace.
> 6. In Business Intelligence Development Studio, process the Analysis Services project.
> 7. In SQL Server Profiler, look for the SQL:BatchCompleted events and for the SQL:BatchStarting events that have the same value in the
>      TransactionID column. Typically, these events contain the SELECT
>      statement in the TextData column. For these events, obtain the session
>      ID in the SPID column.
> 8. To connect to the data source,start SQL Server Management Studio.
> 9. Create a new query, and then run the following Transact-SQL statement.
>
>    select session_id,Transaction_Isolation_Level from sys.dm_exec_sessions
>      where session_id=
>
> *Note In this statement,  is a placeholder for the session ID that you obtained in step 7.*
>
> 10. On the **Results** tab, note the value in the Transaction_Isolation_Level column. This value indicates the
>       transaction isolation level that you are using in the Analysis
>       Services project. When the snapshot transaction isolation level is
>       enabled, the value in the Transaction_Isolation_Level column is 5.
>
> The following table shows the values in the
>   Transaction_Isolation_Level column and the corresponding transaction
>   isolation levels.
>
> [image: table showing transaction isolation levels]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919160/how-to-enable-the-snapshot-transaction-isolation-level-in-sql-server-2